# Identify this TV show from early 2000s with aliens, implants, and an alien-human hybrid

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I remember watching a show in the 2000's. I remember these two people having a little girl and the aliens helping them, so she turns out to be part alien. I also remember some part of the series, the government was exploring one of the alien ships with twins who were psychic and they died with blood coming out of their noses. At some point, the government puts a helmet thing on the girl's head to prevent her from talking to the aliens and a soldier keeps her company.

I think at the end of the series, the girl removes all the alien implants from the people and then she goes with the aliens. This is all I know and I have been looking for this show for forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably [Taken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taken_(miniseries)), a miniseries produced by Steven Spielberg.

The little girl, Allie Clarke (revealed to be an alien hybrid) was played by  well-known child actress Dakota Fanning.

I'll address the points you remember with quotes from the series' Wikipedia page and character wiki page linked off it.

Twins who die exploring a ship:

> Gladys and Mavis are the famed Erenberg twins, and they're psychically linked to each other. They are taken to New Mexico as guinea pigs in Owen Crawford and Dr. Kreutz's alien program. They demonstrate their abilities when one of the twins visualizes a bunch of flowers, while the other draws a mentally accurate depiction. Crawford and Kreutz hope the Erenburg twins could fly the alien ship that crashed near Roswell. But those who enter the base don't come out alive: colonel Crawford intentionally makes them stay in the ship, thus exposing them to enough energy to kill them - a property of the alien technology that was already known.

Allie removes implants:

> After John taught Allie how to remove the implants, she used the ability on everyone that came to protect her at the farmhouse so they wouldn't be taken anymore, and would no longer be afraid.

Leaves with the aliens:

> When the hybrid Allie Keys departs with the aliens, the Artifact is teleported away with them.

Comment: Exactly right, my thinking too when reading the OP. +1

Comment: Superb miniseries.